# Firefox and <li> vertical alignment

Tags: css, firefox, html-lists, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a horizontal menu bar that's flush with the top of the screen. It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, the LIs are half cut off.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efq2u/1/).

How do I get it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .topmenu li:hover a, .topmenu a:hover { position:absolute; display:inline-block; 
  width:inherit; height:30px; background:inherit; text-align:center; }
```

That should work for you. Just add position absolute to this section.

Comment: It's still cut off in Firefox, just not by as much. And it's too far down in Chrome now.